# Custom eclipse template to make setter return this object?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I need to custom eclipse setter template to return this object, like this

```
public Person setName(String name){
    this.name=name;
    return this;
}
```

but Java->Code Style->Templates only allow me to custom setter body part, not method definition. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't offer a solution to allow you to modify the Eclipse template for this, however can I suggest that you rethink what you're doing here?

If you check the [JavaBeans spec](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) you'll see that when you define your methods in this way they are no longer valid property setters. Setters should have a `void` return type; you may regret creating these non-standard beans in the long run. For instance, try using `java.beans.Introspector` to gather bean info for your class and you'll see that your property 'setters' are not found.

I know it's nice to be able to quickly initialise your beans with chained calls like:

```
new Person().setName("John Smith").setDateOfBirth(...).setAddress(...)
```

Can I suggest as an alternative you use standard setters (that return `void`) and instead introduce builder methods like:

```
public Person withName(String name) {
    this.setName(name);
    return this;
}
```

Your quick single line construction then looks like:

```
new Person().withName("John Smith").withDateOfBirth(...).withAddress(...)
```

I find the 'with' prefix reads nicely too.

Comment: I just wish there was a way to get eclipse to generate the 'with' method when a setter is generated.  Still not figured out how.

Comment: The fast code plugin will handle this for you.  The java beans spec is hele broken and has been for a long time.  Decide carefully wether or not you actually care about the bean spec, I know I never actually have.

Comment: I personally don't care much about the beans spec. I value more a possibility to generate immutable POJO's where each setter method returns a modified copy of the object

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Fast Code Eclipse Plugin](http://fast-code.sourceforge.net/) to do this pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, all you can do is edit the "Window->Preferences->Java->Code Style->Code->Setter body" template in Java like so:

```
${field} = ${param};
return this;
```

While this will not automatically set the return type for you, Eclipse does throw a red squiggly at you for every one of your setters, which you can then hover over and select "Change method return type to 'yourTypeHere'".